# Where do I fail with plotting Spiral of Cornu?

Tags: pstricks

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=5}
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1.2pt,algebraic](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psplotDiffEqn[whichabs=0,whichord=1,plotpoints=900]{0}{8}{0 0}{cos(Pi*x^2/2)|sin(Pi*x^2/2)}
\psplotDiffEqn[whichabs=0,whichord=1,plotpoints=900]{0}{-8}{0 0}{cos(Pi*x^2/2)|sin(Pi*x^2/2)}
\rput(0.505,0.5){\color{red} $+$}
\rput(-0.505,-0.5){\color{red} $+$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, when I see at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral?fbclid=IwAR35IhCPv5A56yeLvVWqgmZq_dlIX-EEH5C_aMdLj-I8og8k0AKGSroNUxU

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That are two different equations! With

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psset{unit=5}
\begin{pspicture}[linewidth=1.2pt,algebraic](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=5](-1,-1)(1,1)
\psset{linecolor=blue}
\psplotDiffEqn[whichabs=0,whichord=1,plotpoints=900]{0}{8}{0 0}{cos(x^2)|sin(x^2)}
\psplotDiffEqn[whichabs=0,whichord=1,plotpoints=900]{0}{-8}{0 0}{cos(x^2)|sin(x^2)}
\psdots[dotscale=2,linecolor=red,dotstyle=+](! Pi 2 div sqrt 2 div dup)%
       (! Pi 2 div sqrt -2 div dup)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

you'll get the same ... but is has its fixpoints *not* in P(-0.5,-0.5) and P(0.5,0.5)

[image]

Comment: \rput(0.63,0.63){\color{red} $+$}\rput(-0.63,-0.63){\color{red} $+$} :-)

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: Oh, I see ah, I didn't read the contents of Euler spiral clearly. Thank for this answer.